# twig best practice regarding template locations

Tags: php, templates, twig

My site isn't using a front controller pattern or anything fancy, it's currently a bunch of php files in folders.

e.g:

```
http://www.example.com/customer/account-settings.php
```

maps direcctly to:

```
/var/www/sites/example/http/customer/account-settings.php
```

I've started playing with twig, and wonder what the best practice for locating the template files is?

Should I put them all in

```
/var/www/sites/exammple/templates/
```

or should I put them alongside their corresponding .php file?

```
/var/www/sites/example/http/customer/account-settings.twig
/var/www/sites/example/http/index.twig
```

etc?

Comment: This isn't really particularly suitable for SO because it's only going to provoke opinion-based responses. You could argue the case for either of your suggestions.

Comment: So where do you suggest I ask it?  It's exactly those opions that I wish to garner.

Comment: Nowhere on the StackExchange network I'm afraid. There are good reasons for it - it's not just to annoy people. Have a read here if you're interested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  reddit then.

Answer (score 2):

I would place all files in one directory and than create a configuration variable like

```
$templatesDir='/var/www/sites/exammple/templates/';
```

to reference the location.

That way views are organized and not scattered around the project. If for some reason you want to change their location to another directory you just have to change the `$templatesDir` variable in one place.